# "I like him" or "I liked him"

Tags: tense

I often use this:

> I like him/her

But sometimes, I hear people say:

> I liked him/her

But the person referred to is not dead/deceased, so why use the past tense?

Comment: Without proper context, it's always hard to give a specific answer. But perhaps it's a simple case of the [past tense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_tense), wherein a person says he liked him/her in the past and doesn't do so now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes the past tense is used after the first encounter to express one's impression of a person:

(*After dinner*)

> A: So what did you think of Ryan?
>
> B: I liked him. (=I thought he was nice)

(*After a lecture*)

> A: I hate that professor. He's so scattered.
>
> B: I liked him. I think this is going to be a great class. (=first class with him)

(*After a concert*)

> A: Sting is great in concert!
>
> B: I liked him too. I'm going to buy that album. (=first live Sting concert)

Comment: your second answer, A took the class before right ?

Comment: Yes, most likely. Otherwise she would have said "hated."